# Handle exception + await

Tags: c#, exception, async-await

I have the following code:

```
try
{
     await Task.Run(() => myAppClient.CreateResourceRecord());
}
catch (MyApplicationException dnsException)
{
   // Exception code
}
```

The `MyApplicationException` is thrown during `myAppClient.CreateResourceRecord()` but it is not caught in the catch (MyApplicationException dnsException) statement.
How can it be solved?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this function is really throwing this exception. Probably, you are misinterpreting what you see. Post CreateResourceRecord.

Comment: @usr - I can`t publish the code. I checked in the debugger that MyApplicationException is thrown

Comment: Create a repro (`throw new MyApplicationException();`), then. You'll find that you cannot create a repro because your interpretation was just wrong.

Comment: @usr I don`t understand what you are saying - I just copy/paste my code

Comment: Try: `await Task.Run(() => { throw new MyApplicationException(); });`.

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537614(v=vs.110).aspx ... Task wraps exceptions inside AggregateException

Comment: @MarkoDevcic and `await` unwraps it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @usr's comments:

As can be seen by running this small but complete console application example, the exception does get caught.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = foo();
        t.Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class MyApplicationException : Exception { }

    static async Task foo()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { throw new MyApplicationException(); });
            Console.WriteLine("Completed without exception");
        }
        catch (MyApplicationException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

Exception caught

See: http://dotnetpad.net/ViewPaste/dJQgaYiqtEqqGTCiZJjdgw

Comment: Given the information in the question this is basically the best answer that can be given.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that `Task` works in another thread so exception also is thrown in another thread. To catch exception from `Task` try something like this:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => myAppClient.CreateResourceRecord());
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    ae.Handle((x) =>
    {
        if (x is MyApplicationException)
        {
            // Exception code
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you `await` a task it's exception is re-throw in the thread that awaits it.  It also unwraps the aggregate exception and rethrows the first exception in it.